How to See / Generate a List ALL Slicers Attached To / Controlling a Excel Pivot Table
In Excel I can go to a specific SLICER, right click, select Report Connects, and see a list of all PIVOT TABLES in my Excel workbook with checkboxes to identify the subset of PIVOT TABLES that are being actively filtered by that specific SLICER.
My question is how do I go the other way ...
How do I go to a specific PIVOT TABLE and see a list of all SLICERS that are linked to actively filter that specific PIVOT TABLE.
If this is not possible with the current Excel commands / functionality, then does someone have MACRO code that can generate this information.
I searched the web and this forum and could not find specific solution to my quest.  I have a PIVOT TABLE that I can tell is being controlled by a SLICER in my big complex dashboard with dozens of worksheet tabs and dozens of slicers spread across the various worksheets.
